# Version 5.11.0, Event custom fields not carried over to repeat events

Tags: repeating-events

We use version 5.11.0 and we're still having this issue. Is it possible to see if a solution has been introduced?

Comment: Try testing your scenario on the public demo at https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org

Answer (score 2):

I think this is now [fixed](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/14063/) and should be part of 5.14. You can either wait for 5.14 release or apply patch from [here](https://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/14063.patch).

Cheers

Pradeep

Comment: Thanks Pradeep for your answer but we tried 5.14 and we're still having the same issue. Is there another way that this can be resolved? 
Thanks again.

Comment: Can you try this patch https://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/14480.patch